# Amazon ec2 Java mysql

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to setup an Amazon EC2 with tomcat and mysql. Both are up and running, both are in same instance. My confusions is, what jdbc url I have to use to connect my database on the same instance

```
<bean id="masterDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"> 
     <property name="driverClassName">                
         <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>       
     </property>        
     <property name="url">          
         <value>WHAT TO ADD HERE</value>                    
     </property>
     .....
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to use localhost. Not sure. Though I will try.

Comment: If they're running on the same instance, shouldn't they run on the same host? Why wouldn't using localhost be a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add them like this:

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/_dbName" />
<property name="username" value="your username" />
<property name="password" value="your password" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/database_name?user=your_username&password=your_greatsqlpw
```

or

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/database_name?user=your_username&password=your_greatsqlpw
```

As long as your server is secure you should not be concerned about security too much since the connections are only internal in the server.